# How to convert XML file having "ref ids" and "ids" in java

Tags: java, xml

I have a sample xml like below.I have  a requirement were I need to cross reference various xml attributes. I have identified the below format, but not sure how to interpret this in java.

How do i interpret this xml in java. For example, how do I retireve details of a teacher with teacher  id="T72100";

```
<schedule term="Fall" year="98" xmlns:data="x-schema:idSchema.xml"
                                xmlns:ref="x-schema:refSchema.xml">
  <classes>
    <data:class id="ENGL6004">
      <title>From Here to Eternity: Studies in the Futureenter code here
        and other Temporal Genres</title>
      <ref:teacherRef ref="T31330"/>
      <students>
        <ref:student ref="S50245"/>
        <ref:student ref="S87901"/>
        <ref:student ref="S19272"/>
        <ref:student ref="S48984"/>
      </students>
    </data:class>
    <data:class id="HIST6010">
      <title>The You Decade: A History of Finger Pointing
        in Post-War America</title>
      <ref:teacher ref="T72100"/>
      <students>
        <ref:student ref="S60912"/>
        <ref:student ref="S87901"/>
        <ref:student ref="S84281"/>
        <ref:student ref="S44098"/>
      </students>
    </data:class>
    <data:class id="ENGL6020">
      <title>Reading between the Lines: The Literature
        of Waiting</title>
      <ref:teacher ref="T31330"/>
      <students>
        <ref:student ref="S84281"/>
        <ref:student ref="S19272"/>
        <ref:student ref="S48984"/>
        <ref:student ref="S44098"/>
      </students>
    </data:class>
  </classes>
  <teachers>
    <data:teacher id="T31330">
      <name>Margaret Doornan</name>
      <position>Associate Professor</position>
      <classes>
        <ref:class ref="ENGL6004"/>
        <ref:class ref="ENGL6020"/>
      </classes>
    </data:teacher>
    <data:teacher id="T72100">
      <name>Hal Canter</name>
      <position>Instructor</position>
      <classes>
        <ref:class ref="HIST6010"/>
      </classes>
    </data:teacher>
  </teachers>
  <students>
    <data:student id="S44098">
      <name>Kelly Griftman</name>
      <year>Senior</year>
      <status>full-time</status>
      <classes>
        <ref:class ref="HIST6010"/>
        <ref:class ref="ENGL6020"/>
      </classes>
    </data:student>
    <data:student id="S48984">
      <name>Norbert James</name>
      <year>Senior</year>
      <status>full-time</status>
      <classes>
        <ref:class ref="ENGL6004"/>
        <ref:class ref="ENGL6020"/>
      </classes>
    </data:student>
    </students>
</schedule>
```

**Update**: Tried to use XPath to get the desired output but maybe either my expression is incorrect or I don't understand Xpath so well:

```
String expression = "/schedule/teachers/teacher[@id='T72100']";
        Node node = (Node) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
        if(null != node) {
            NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0;null!=nodeList && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
                if(nod.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getNodeName() + " : " + nod.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
            }
        }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name : Hal Canter
position : Instructor
classes :
```

This gives no information about the classes. How can I retrieve details of classes as well.
The expected output is

```
name : Hal Canter
    position : Instructor
    classes :
        id: HIST6010
        title: "The You Decade: A History of Finger Pointing in Post-War America"
```

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html and comment if there's any part that you'd like clarification of.

Comment: Thanks for response David. I had tried using XPath(though not an expert) to interpret but failed to get information what I require.

Comment: Did you manage to write a program that applied some XPath?  I am asking so I can work out whether to help you with the Java programming, or to help you work out a suitable XPath expression.

Comment: Hi David..I have updated my original post with my code. please suggest.

Comment: Right, I was just reading it.  It looks like you came quite a long way to solving this (and I think `teacher` in your XPath should have been `data:teacher` to match your input).  I think when you come to the `classes` node, you'll need to iterate through it, the same way you iterated through the `teacher` node; that is, with `nod.getChildNodes()`.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to traverse an arbitrary number of levels into the subtree under the node you identify?  Or will it always just have one or two levels?

Comment: It is going to be arbitrary number of levels.

Comment: So you're going to have to write some kind of recursive method to print out the contents of one node - either its value if it's a text node, or its children if it's an element node.  From looking at your code sample above, I figure you won't need my help with the actual coding.  Am I right?

Comment: I am unable to extend this to get the classes information. Can you please give a sample code to retrieve classes info for that particular teacher?

Comment: OK, I would suggest that you move the line `if(null != node)` and everything in the `{ }` that follow it into a separate method, with `node` as a parameter.  You'll call that method from the point where the `if` statement is currently.  Then you'll add an extra call to that method, inside the method itself, underneath the `System.out.println` line - and that will give you the recursion.  Is that clear?

Comment: I will try the recursive and post the output in a while. thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, Sangeeta, and good luck.  I am going to go offline for a few hours now, but I'll come back here later and see how you're getting on.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, XPath does not use the namespace prefixes definend in the document. You need either to `xpath.setNamespaceContext(...)` with your prefixes, or use [a library](http://xmlbeam.org) that handles all that automatically.

Here is reading the teacher as object done with XMLBeam. Reading Class elements is simply the same.

```
public class TestXMLParsing {

public interface Schedule {

    public interface Teacher {
        @XBRead("./classes/ref:class/@ref")
        String[] getClassRefs();
        @XBRead("./name")
        String getName();
        @XBRead("./position")
        String getPosition();
    }

    @XBRead("//data:teacher[@id='{0}']")
    Teacher getTeacher(String id);
}

@Test
public void readTeacherAndClassesRef() throws IOException {
    Schedule schedule = new XBProjector(Flags.TO_STRING_RENDERS_XML).io().url("resource://schedule.xml").read(Schedule.class);
    Teacher teacher = schedule.getTeacher("T72100");
    System.out.println(teacher.getName()+"\n"+teacher.getPosition()+"\nclasses:");
    for (String classRef : teacher.getClassRefs()) {
        System.out.println(classRef);
    }
}
```

}

To my eyes this looks more straight forward and understandable as processing the DOM by hand.

Comment: This is true, but it's not really an answer.  Also, Sangeeta has managed to extract the required "teacher" node already, and processing the children of that node doesn't really require any special treatment of the namespaces.

Comment: Where did you read about the successful extraction of the teacher? Sangeeta needs to provide namespace prefixes, or disable namespaces in the xml parser completely, or use a library. XMLBeam is suitable,  because it does exactly this.

Comment: She updated her question to show her output.  I'm not sure why her XPath expression is working when she hasn't specified whatever namespace `data:` is indicating.  But then she said it was just the classes information that she was missing.

Comment: You are right. She gets a filled nodelist. So its the ` nod.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()` that does not work. Should be `+ ((Element)nod.getFirstChild()).getAttribute("ref")` instead. FirstChild can be anything, e.g. a text node with just a linefeed.

Comment: Right, which means she should iterate through the children, and handle each one the way it needs to be handled - which in her case is going to involve recursion.

Comment: This gets really complicated for such a simple task. Now I definetly would recommend to use a library. Provided an example in my answer.

Comment: Wow, this is a much better answer now.  +1.

Comment: True that! It is getting really complex. I will try using a library . thanks for the example.